# Linux terminal emulator with custom line height and character spacing?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm looking for a Linux terminal emulator which has similar features to OS X's Terminal.app in terms of being able to customise line height and character spacing. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/194264/how-do-i-change-the-line-spacing-in-terminal/983242 for more answers.

Answer (score 2):

**Rxvt Unicode** has support for this.

from `man urxvt`:

> -lsp number
>
> Compile frills: Lines (pixel height) to insert between each row of the display. Useful to work around font rendering problems; resource lineSpace.
>
> -letsp number
>
> Compile frills: Amount to adjust the computed character width by to control overall letter spacing. Negative values will tighten up the letter spacing, positive values will space letters out more. Useful to work around odd font metrics; resource letterSpace.